# Error while uploading in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, xampp

I'm trying to make a image upload in lavarel 4. The upload passes by

`The file "C:\xampp\tmp\phpD1F3.tmp" does not exist`

This is my upload code :

```php
$file = Input::file('image');

// Get extension
$extension =$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

// Generate a file name
$fileName = 'pool' . Str::quickRandom();
$fileNameExtension = $fileName . '.' . $extension;

// Process upload
Input::file('image')->move(public_path() . '/uploads/images/app/pools/original/', $fileNameExtension);
```

`

I don't know why i get this error , please can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Have you check whether the file that you POST to your server is actually stored in the tmp folder? or whether the folder has the write permission from your web server.

Comment: On the other hand, you could also use the laravel method **Input::hasFile('image')** function to check whether the file exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably making some operations on "uploaded" file after moving it to server by `move()` function. Please make sure there is no operation made on temporary file after calling `Input::file('image')->move()` function.